# How do you remove all traces of tracked changes from a Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word

My question is simple:  **How do you remove all traces of tracked changes from a Word document?**

I want to send a manuscript to my boss without my tracked changes showing.  I do not in any way want my tracked changes to be visible, or to become visible. I do not want to convert the file to plain text - it should remain a Word document.

Comment: You can try Copy (Ctrl + A then ctrl+C) and open new word document and there Ctrl+V then save new document with any name.

Answer (score 4):

From the track changes menu, accept all changes, or alternatively disable track changes and the final version will also be the only thing you see.

If tracking the current changes is viable to you, you can choose to hide the display of it, but it'll only be to your user, and for all documents, so you probably don't want that. (I name it because you might find that option and don't realise the impact.)